# Strange connection between Bernouilli, Uniform and Geometric distributions

Tags: distributions, mathematical-statistics, lognormal-distribution, bernoulli-distribution, geometric-distribution

*Final update on 11/29/2019: I have worked on this a bit more, and wrote an article summarizing all the main findings. You can read it [here](https://www.datasciencecentral.com/profiles/blogs/chaos-attractors-in-machine-learning-systems).*

Let us consider $Z = X_1 + X_1 X_2 + X_1 X_2 X_3 +\cdots$ where the $X_i$'s are i.i.d. I proved in my previous answer (see [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/435049/variance-of-z-x-1-x-1-x-2-x-1-x-2-x-3-cdots)) that $Z$ has a geometric distribution if and only if $X_i$ has a Bernouilli distribution. Thus the geometric distribution is an attractor for this system. Also, it is an *isolated* attractor in the sense that there is only one way it can be attained: only if $X_i$ is Bernouilli.

**Theorem**

Now let us consider the following shifted Bernouilli distribution: $$P\Big(X_i = \frac{1}{2}\Big) = P\Big(X_i = -\frac{1}{2}\Big) = \frac{1}{2}.$$

Then $Z$ is uniform on $[-1, 1]$. Also $Z$ is uniform on $[-1, 1]$ if and only if $X_i$ has the shifted Bernouilli distribution in question.

**Proof**

The proof of this fact is based on the following relationship for the $k$-th moments (see [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/435049/variance-of-z-x-1-x-1-x-2-x-1-x-2-x-3-cdots/)):
$$E(Z^k) = E[(X_i(1+Z))^k]=E(X_i^k)E[(1+Z)^k].$$
Assume a uniform distribution on $[-1, 1]$ for $Z$. Then we have

- $E(Z^k) = 1/(k+1)$ if $k$ is odd, and is equal to zero otherwise,
- $E[(1+Z)^k] = 2^k/(k+1)$,

We also have:

- $E[X_i^k]= 1/2^k$ if $k$ is odd, and is equal to zero otherwise.

Thus the only way we can have $E(Z^k) = E(X_i^k)E[(1+Z)^k]$ is if all the moments of $Z$ are those of a uniform distribution on $[-1, 1]$. Thus, $Z$ has the prescribed distribution.

To prove the converse, note that in order for $Z$ to be uniform on $[-1, 1]$ then $E[X_i^k]= 1/2^k$ if $k$ is odd, 0 otherwise. The only distribution having these moments is the shifted Bernouilli distribution for $X_i$.

**Connection with the binary numeration system**

If $Z = X_1 + X_1 X_2 + X_1 X_2 X_3 + \cdots$ and $X_i$ has the shifted Bernouilli distribution mentioned earlier (thus $Z\in [-1, 1]$), and 
$$Z+1 = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{B_k}{2^k}, \mbox{ with } B_k \in \{0, 1\}$$

then
$$X_1 = B_0 -\frac{1}{2} \mbox{ and } X_k = \frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{2B_{k-1}-1}{2B_{k-2}-1} \mbox{ if } k\geq 2.$$

Conversely, if $k\geq 0$, then

$$B_k = \frac{1}{2}+2^k \cdot \prod_{i=1}^{k+1} X_i.$$

For instance, if $Z = \frac{1}{5}$, then the $k$-th digit ($k = 1, 2, \cdots$) of $Z$ in the new numeration system introduced here is $X_k= (-1)^{k-1}/2$.

**Connection with singular distributions**

In most cases, if $X_i$ is discrete, then $Z$ is nowhere differentiable. A typical example is the following: if $P(X_i = -\frac{1}{2}) = \frac{1}{4} = 1-P(X_i = \frac{1}{2})$ then see below the percentile distribution for $Z$, it's clearly a singular distribution on $[-1,1]$:

[image]

To the contrary, if $P(X_i = -\frac{1}{2}) = \frac{1}{2} = P(X_i = \frac{1}{2})$, then the shape of the percentile distribution is a perfect diagonal, see picture below.

[image]

These charts were produced using 20,000 deviates for $Z$, each based on 200 terms $X_1, X_1 X_2,\cdots,  X_1 X_2\cdots X_{200}$.

**Question (updated)**

Can you find other distributions for $X_i$ (a continuous distribution if possible) resulting in $Z$ having a well known distribution?

The key here is that $X_i$ and $1+Z$ act as if they were independent. And the distribution of $Z$ is also that of $X_i(1+Z)$. Characteristic functions (based on the Fourier transform) are of no use. Instead, the Mellin transformation, denoted as $M$, is useful here, as the Mellin transform of a product of independent random variables is the product of the individual Mellin transforms (see Wikipedia article [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_distribution).) In short, $M(Z)=M(X_i)M(1+Z)$. I tried a log-normal distribution for $X_i$ and $Z$ was very well approximated by a log-normal on $[-3, 3]$, but it is not an exact solution.

**Why is Log-normal not working?**

I tried the following log-normal distribution: $X_i = \exp(Y_i)/5$ with $Y_i$ being Normal($0, 1$). Thus $X_i$ is log-normal and has the following moments (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution)): $E(X_i^k) = 5^{-k}\cdot\exp(k^2/2), k = 0, 1, 2,\cdots$. Since $E(Z^k) = E(X_i^k)E[(1+Z)^k]$, it is possible to compute the exact value of $E(Z^k)$. The approximate values are

- $E(Z) \approx 0.491967814042304$
- $E(Z^2) \approx 0.832403517661211$
- $E(Z^3)    \approx 12.796705133476$

These values are obtained using the following formulas:

$$E(Z) = \frac{E(X_i)}{1-E(X_i)}$$

$$E(Z^2) = \frac{E(X_i^2)(1+E(X_i))}{(1-E(X_i))(1-E(X_i^2))}$$

$$E(Z^3) =\frac{E(X_i^3)(1+3E(Z)+3E(Z^2))}{(1-E(X_i^3))}$$

Now let us assume that $Z$ is log-normal. We must have $E(Z^k) = \exp(k\mu + k^2\sigma^2/2)$ for some parameters $\mu$ and $\sigma$. Solving for
$\exp(\mu + \sigma^2/2) \approx 0.491967814042304$ and $\exp(2\mu + 4\sigma^2/2)\approx 0.832403517661211$ yields:

- $\mu \approx -1.32696498721330$
- $\sigma^2 / 2 \approx 0.61762300397038$

Now $E(Z^3) = \exp(3\mu + 9\sigma^2/2) \approx 4.843860729265$. This is very different from the value computed earlier (namely, $E(Z^3) \approx 12.796705133476$) and thus we must conclude that $Z$ can not be log-normal.

Comment: Each term $X_1 X_2 X_3 ... X_n$ you are either adding or subtracting $\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^n$, based on a coin flip. So you can see your product also as $\sum_{n=1}^\infty X_i \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^n$ with $P(X=1) = P(X=-1) = 1/2$. This means that your uniform variable is not uniform on $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: I wonder what numbers form the probability space. It is a discrete distribution with infinitely many possibilities. Does that exist?

Comment: Maybe it's a https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_distribution

Comment: It looks uniform on $[-1, 1]$. However, most examples involving a discrete distribution for $X_i$ results in a singular distribution for $Z$. The shifted Bernouilli and regular Bernouilli appear to be exceptions, possibly the only ones.

Comment: Uniform on $[-1,1] \in \mathbb{R}$ or $[-1,1] \in \mathbb{Q}$ or something else? For any number $z$ you have $P(Z = z) = 0$.